# Angular won't find named router outlet

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have two router outlets in my application. One is the primary router outlet and other router outlet is in component template which is loaded with lazy loaded module. Name of the router outlet is `pr` and I have defined path for that route inside the lazy loaded module like this

`{outlet:'pr',path: 'students', component: StudentTableComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}`

Inside the component I have router link with this.

```
<button mat-button mat-stroked-button 
[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { pr:'students'} }]">View Students
 </button>
```

In the same component I have put the `<router-outlet name="pr"></router-outlet>`. After clicking the link app is correctly navigated showing `project/132/(pr:students)`. No errors appears ,although not showing the component. If I put the router outlet in the main component which have primary outlet it loads. Ex:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<router-outlet name="pr"></router-outlet>
```

But after moving outlet elsewhere Angular won't identify the outlet

Comment: Did you add the `RouterModule.forRoot` to the module containing the component?

Comment: @callback yes, in my lazy loaded module I have added RouterModule.forChild(). Every path  I mentioned are in that module.

Comment: I find the Chrome/Firefox extension [Augury](https://augury.rangle.io/) works wonders when facing router woes